# calculate maximum distance with large vectors

Tags: matlab, optimization

ok so I have 2 vectors (A and B) with different lengths (in this example lets say 100000 and 300000) and I wish to obtain the indexes that have the largest difference.
Something like this

```
distAB=bsxfun(@(v1,v2) abs(v1-v2),A,B));
[~,lin_indx]=max(distAB(:));
[x_indx,y_indx]=ind2sub(size(A),lin_indx)
```

The problem here is that my vectors A and B are too large and producing the matrix "distAB" is too expensive. I would wish to obtain the min directly with the bsxfun.

Comment: Please clarify if you want maximum or minimum distance. Your title and code say min, your text says max

Comment: Is `size(A)` right? Shouldn't it be `[numel(A) numel(B)]`?

Comment: So your sizes are `size(A)==[100000,1]` and `size(B)==[300000,1]` and you want to find the points `A(i)` and `B(j)`, such that `abs(A(i)-B(j))` is as small as it gets?

Comment: Yeah, that "obtain the indexes that have the **largest** difference" is still confusing me.

Comment: So is it minimum or maximum? Smallest or largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **maximize distance**, the search can be reduced to **just two candidate pairs**: `max(A)`, `min(B))` or `min(A)`, `max(B))`.

So just try those two pairs:

```
[ma_val, ma_ind] = min(A);
[Ma_val, Ma_ind] = max(A);
[mb_val, mb_ind] = min(B);
[Mb_val, Mb_ind] = max(B);
diff1 = abs(Mb_val-ma_val);
diff2 = abs(Ma_val-mb_val);
if diff1 > diff2
    result_ind_A = ma_ind;
    result_ind_B = Mb_ind;
    result_value = diff1;
else
    result_ind_A = Ma_ind;
    result_ind_B = mb_ind;
    result_value = diff2;
end
```

---

If you want to **minimize distance**: sort the concatenation of `A` and `B`, keeping track of which element is from `A` and which from `B`:

```
C = sortrows([A(:) zeros(numel(A),1); B(:) ones(numel(B),1)] ,1);
%// C(k,2)==0 indicates element k comes from A; 1 indicates from B
```

Now, use a `for` loop to traverse all elements in `C(:,1)` that come from `B`. For each such element, find the two elements from `A` that are located closest above and to below left in `C`. Those are the only candidates from `A` to be nearest to that element from `A`.

So for each element from `B` you have two candidates from `A`, which reduces the complexity of the problem significantly.

Comment: Would have gone for sorting also.

Comment: nice. that should solve the above question. Yet i forgot to say that I have 3 directions (x,y,z) which probably make our cases go from 2 to 8. still solvable. as soon as I try this I will come back.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro: Please add clarifications to your question. It is still unclear if you are searching for the smallest(minimum) or largest(maximum) distance between two points. Also you just now mentioned that you are in fact not dealing with `n/m-by-1` vectors, but with `n/m-by-3` arrays!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `distAB` this way with the built-in `@minus` which could be more efficient -

```
distAB = abs(bsxfun(@minus,A(:).',B(:)))
```

Comment: that is similar to what I have and will not solve the problem as the matrix distAB will need to be produced. the idea here is that I never want to generate the 5x7 distAB and then calculate the minimum, but instead calculate the minimum at the same time. instead of the 5, 7 imagine a 10000x100000 matrix

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro If they are so large, use a loop

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro Yeah with that huge input, you can't think of a vectorized approach!

Comment: @Luis Mendo yes I can do that but then it will take a huge amount of time in MATLAB. perhaps I can compile a mex. I was just trying to figure out if there was another more optimized way.

Comment: Wait... See my answer

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro Or you can probably divide that huge input data into smaller blocks and then apply bsxfun on these blocks separately?

Answer (score 1):

*Luis*' approach of sorting will probably be the fastest. But if you have the statistics toolbox installed, you could use the function [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html), which makes for a simple yet efficient solution.
(There are also some similar free versions of this on the File Exchange. Look for: [*kd tree nearest neighbor*](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=kd+tree+nearest+neighbor))

One extra benefit of this solution is that it also works for 2D, 3D, ..., nD data.

```
[Is, D] = knnsearch(A,B,'K',1);
[~,j] = min(D); i = Is(j);
[A(i), B(j)]
```

Comment: Depending on the data-sizes `knnsearch` either does a brute-force full search on all points (as in `min(pdist2(...`) or builds a *k-d tree* which is basically like a binary tree, but the condition if something goes in the left-branch or right-branch alternates with the depth of the tree and basically cycles through the dimensions (which in 1D makes it a binary tree). Searching for the *k nearest neighbors* to a specific point is easy then (in terms of computational complexity).